# Netbeans project doesn't run on localhost

Tags: server, apache2, php, netbeans

I set up my ubuntu enviroment correctly, installed apache2 which is running, localhost from firefox gives `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page` but whenever i try to access my website i created using netbeans I get 404 error. `http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php` is the url netbeans tries to run my code. All of the settings were default when creating this project. Source folder: `/var/www/PhpProject2` When trying to run the project I get this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /PhpProject2/index.php was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new default root folder of apache is `/var/www/html`, thus your Source folder should read `/var/www/html/PhpProject2`.

Comment: tried it. still the same error: `Not Found

The requested URL /html/PhpProject2/index.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: the requested url should still read `/PhpProject2/index.php`

Comment: It worked after i deleted /html/ from the url. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project in the "Projects" on the left.
Right click on the project and open properties.
Choose Run Configuration.
Change URL in the "Project URL" by adding the port number your Mampp,Xampp is using.

Like so from: http://localhost/LearningPHP/
To: http://localhost:8888/LearningPHP/